# custom controller session reset

Tags: magento-1.9, session

I am facing strange issue. Session is reset on custom module controller. have anyone face the similar issue? 
My code is simple

```
class Test_Testing_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    { 

        $this->loadLayout();                 
        $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
}
```

It is related to **customer session** other pages are working normally changing the **login** to **logout** but not on **custom module page**. I am not using any custom session only Magento own session.

My config.xml

```
 <config>
  <modules>
    <Test_Testing>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Test_testing>
  </modules>
   <frontend>
    <routers>
      <testing>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Test_Testing</module>
          <frontName>testing</frontName>
        </args>
      </testing>
    </routers>
   </frontend>
```

Comment: Could you give us some more info? Does your module add any session functionality, or did you specify a namespace in the config xml?

Comment: @mizuti i update the question.